# Can't make a replacement ref "permanent"

Tags: git

I had to merge two branches into another, and I wanted to capture/record this history. First I tried an octopus merge, but the branches were too different and Git refused to perform the merge. To be clear, there are three branches involved, not two.

As an alternative, I checked out the files I needed, from each branch, did a three way diff on each set of files, then committed. To record the history, I then used `git replace --graft`. Aside from having to handle the merge without Git's held (aside from it keeping track of the files in the other branches...which is a big deal) it went well.

I then found out that rather than this new commit being part of the branch proper, it is instead substituted for the actual commit whenever something calls for it. This is not desirable. Admittedly, I don't know of any disadvantages with having things handled in this fashion, but that isn't to say there aren't negative side effects. Besides, it seems messy and improper.

Looking up a solution, I find that `git filter-branch -- --all` should do the trick...except it doesn't seem to. First off, I expected at least the replacement commit's hash to change. Also, the errors I'm getting seem to indicate something went wrong.

```
Rewrite 500495d563d9209cf21d660e7d78d2a7677e570b (291/318) (6 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/cleanup
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/planning' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/devel' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/nm/cleanup
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/nm/planning' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/nm/devel' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/replace/3ec2686d2ae2ba9e7583836e26e25c7bd0b8aa19' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-01-11' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-02-11' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-10-23' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-10-24' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-12-27' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/sent/18-12-31' is unchanged
```

The questions are then "How else could I have done this", "did something actually go wrong", and/or "how can I 'fix' this?" I understand `git graft` is another way to handle the first step but (1) it seems to be some horribly hacked together solution and I've read its advised against and (2) I'm having trouble finding docs on `git graft` leading me to believe it has been removed in favor of `git replace --graft`.

In case it matters, I had already run `git gc` prior to running `git filter-branch`. I actually performed the `git replace` part early last week, and only saw that it might be a good idea to "cement" the commit today.

Comment: Sorry to ask this very basic question but... what do you try to achieve? Merging two branches together *does* record the history of both parents. Also, why an octopus merge for two branches? oO Why did a classic merge not fit your needs?

Comment: I'm merging two branching into another, so there are three branches involved. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll clarify.

Comment: If you've gc'ed, the refs will all have been packed. It's better to avoid inspecting `.git/refs` directly; use `git for-each-ref` instead. I'd have to experiment a bit, or study the shell script, to see what filter-branch does with the actual refs/replace/ references themselves, but in general, when it's copying all the commits it can reach from `--all`, it reads the source commit without disabling replacement, so that if it asks for commit `a123456...` and that's replace by `b789abc...` it will copy `b789abc...` instead of `a123456...`. That's what "cements" the replacements.

Comment: If you have a bunch of existing branches and tags whose tip commits are *not* affected by the copying process (because the copied commits are all 100% bit-for-bit identical to their originals all the way through the copying => all copies *are* the originals), you'll get the above `warning`s for each such ref. So that part, at least, seems normal.

Comment: @torek Are you suggesting that by running garbage collection (which I did), repacking the repo in the process, I already cemented the commit?

Comment: No, `git gc` just runs `git pack-refs` and `git pack-refs` *deletes the reference files*, replacing them with a reference *database*. That's why you can't find the *files*, they're in a (flat text file) database. Use `git for-each-ref` and `git update-ref` to access references, don't look for files.

Comment: @torek Oh I see. Thanks. Yeah, its there. I removed that bit of misleading information from my question,