# Force a commit to have additional parents upon commit

Tags: git, merge, commit

This is related to another question of mine: [Can't make a replacement ref "permanent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519270/cant-make-a-replacement-ref-permanent). To be clear, for whatever reason, `git replace --graft` combined with `git filter-branch` isn't working.

I need to merge three branches, but octopus merge fails (files too dissimilar) so I do it all by hand (`git show branch:file > file` then launch `meld`). However, the history is important, so I need to document that `branch` is a parent. Since I can't make replacement refs permentant despite doing what I'm told to in the man files and elsewhere on Stackexchange (`filter-branch`) I seek an alternative.

As can be seen in my existing question, my first thought was to use replacement, but this isn't working as desired (they aren't being "cemented"). Similarly `git graft` seems to be advised against. Also, as mentioned in the linked question, octopus merging fails. Looking through `git commit --help` (the man page) turned up nothing.

Note that I'm not asking about adding additional parents to an old commit. I'm at the tip of the branch that hasn't been pushed, and no commit has this one as a parent.

Comment: If `git replace --graft` followed by a bare filter-branch isn't working, there's something wrong. Your other question doesn't show anything wrong, filter-branch just noticed you pointed it at lots of refs you didn't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at this at a lower level (how exactly DO commits happen) I came across a lovely web page: https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/4-how-trees-are-made.html.

So the answer is to do it by hand.

```
git add file
git write-tree
echo "commit message" | git commit-tree -p branch_A -p branch_B -p branch_C $hash-from-previous-step
git update-ref refs/heads/branch_A $hash-from-previous-step #note I'm on branch_A
```

Voila! I could then write a simple shell command which takes as input a commit message and two other branches (using `HEAD` as the first parent).

For the hell of it, I wrote it as a one liner.

```
git add file && git update-ref refs/heads/branch_A $(echo "commit message" | git commit-tree -p branch_A -p branch_B -p branch_C $(git write-tree))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
git replace --graft @ branch_A branch_B branch_C
git filter-branch
```

I do any major surgery in a scratch repo and push back the results I want, that way if anything goes wrong recovery is literally as easy as walking away:

```
git clone -sb somebranch . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
major surgery here
git push origin whatever
cd -
```

but for something this trivial it's easier to just do it locally and clean out filter-branch's ref backups whenever with

```
git filter-branch -f --setup exit
```

It's perhaps worth noting that all this boils down to doing what's in [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729604/1290731) and taking the commit message from the checked-out commit.

Comment: I suppose I should have made it more clear that `git replace --graft` is not actually an option. This whole question was asked because your solution doesn't work. If you have a way to make it work, please answer the other question of mine instead. I do, however, bring up that `git filter-branch` isn't doing as I expected. Also, this isn't major surgery. Its just an odd commit.

Comment: You keep saying it doesn't work, but (a) your examples don't show it not working, they show filter-branch noticing you didn't need to filter all those refs, and (b) no, the replacement commit id didn't change, filter-branch made a new one, for good reason.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519270/cant-make-a-replacement-ref-permanent). Please stay on topic for this one, which explicitly excludes your answer.

Comment: You do remember that you're here to ask people who know Git to help you, right?  Because you don't?

Comment: I'm just asking you to stay on topic. If you have a way to make my previous attempts at this work, I'd be glad to hear of it. Just not here. Moreover, my previous attempt was a work around. "commit --> replace --> cement" seems more round about then just making the commit I wanted in the first place, which is what this question is asking for. Please don't take this personally.